# Skip the Ruby on Rails validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, linkedin-api

I am using the LinkedIn API. While signing in with the LinkedIn API, active record validation should not work or be skipped.

When a user signs in with LinkedIn then everything is empty, so can we use this point in our logic, and how do we do this?

Comment: Your answer can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-validations).

Answer (score 2):

When you save the model just pass validate: false

```
save(validate: false)
```

Source: [Ruby on Rails guides - Skipping Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-validations)